# Function.prototype.bind implicitly converts numbers to objects

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I was trying to do some functional programming in CoffeeScript and wrote a currying function:

```
curry = (func, ref=null, length=func.length) ->
  (args...) ->
    if args.length >= length
      func.apply ref, args
    else
      curry (func.bind ref, args), ref, length - args.length
```

So naturally, I went about testing it with this simple `add` function:

```
add = (a, b) ->
  a + b

alert add 3.1, -2
alert (curry add)(3.1)(-2)
```

The uncurried `add` returned `1.1` as expected, but the curried `add` returned `"3.1-2"`. For some reason, inside the curried `add`, `typeof a` was changed object while `typeof b` remained number. I've traced the types all the way to the `bind` call, which leads me to conclude that `Function.prototype.bind` was converting the numbers into objects.

[Relevant JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pabyd3wt/)

Why is this happening, and what can I do to prevent the type conversions?

Comment: you should `curry (func.bind ref, args...), ref, length - args.length` otherwise you're binding an array (which is an object and the source of the problem) of args rather than all the args as individual bound arguments - https://jsfiddle.net/pabyd3wt/1/

Comment: Oh wow, I thought bind expected args to be an array, thanks!

Comment: i'm pretty sure you can use `"use strict"` to stop that; it works in [].map()...

Comment: @mingmingrr it's `apply` that uses an array.